# Instagram Basic Display API - This authorization code has been used

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I need to allow users of my platform to link their Instagram account through the Instagram Basic Display API.
When I make the call to get the code to exchange for the Access Token, it is always the same and results in an error in the next step.

These are the steps I'm performing, following [this official guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started):

1. GET request with these parameters: `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXX&scope=user_profile&response_type=code`
2. POST request to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` via cURL in PHP passing the parameters as the second code snippet below
3. GET request with `'https://graph.instagram.com/' . $result->user_id . '?fields=username&access_token=' . $result->access_token` via cURL in PHP

The process fail between 1 and 2, because step one always returns the same code even though **I have made several attempts with different accounts**

This is the HTML form for the code request. Successfully opens the Instagram login page:

```html
<a class="insta-con" href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXX&scope=user_profile&response_type=code">
   <img src="assets/images/instalogo.png" alt="Connetti a Instagram">
   <p>Connect to Instagram</p>
</a>
```

The login form return always the same code, also with different accounts, resulting in error `{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "This authorization code has been used"}` in this next request:

```php
$fields = array(
    'client_id'     => 'XXXXXX',
    'client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'  => 'https://www.XXXXXXX.it/connect.php',
    'code'          => $_GET['code']
);
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);
```

So my question is: Why am I getting always the same code despite different accounts?

Comment: Why are you using a form to trigger this, and not a normal link? Your form is invalid HTML btw., you can not nest `input` into `button`.

Comment: (You should go and reset your client secret first of all now, because you just exposed it in the code above.)

Comment: My mistake. Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem still remains

Comment: I don’t know why you would get the same code each time, that makes little sense. Can you explain what exact steps you are performing here? I.e., login to Facebook/IG first, then call the login dialog, etc.; and what exactly happens in each of those steps? Did you switch the logged-in IG user, or are you still trying this for the same account?

Comment: I've edited the question in more detail, explaining the steps I take. The problem also occurs when attempting with different accounts

Comment: Have you solved this one? we have the same...

Comment: @SebastienC. I answered to the question with the solving steps 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by verifying the business or using the individual verification in the Facebook Developer Console.

Before using the API, **you need to verify your identity** clicking Settings > Basic settings then scroll to **Individual verification** or **Business verification** and complete all the steps.